# jdk path not valid on older android studio mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I download android studio version 1.4 because I want to compile apk from old android studio project, then when ask for jdk location I put jdk location. But android studio did not recognize it.

What is the correct path for jdk in android studio mac?[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWoXm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to compile apk from old android studio project

As far as I know, latest Android Studio can compile old projects just fine. Gradle and its plugins are what build the project, not the IDE.

Maybe since you're using an older version, though, Java 12 would not be recognized as valid, and you'd have to get Java 8, possibly